# View not update after POST although View Model updated

Tags: asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

I am writing ASP.NET Custom Component, I want to update my view with following code below:

```
 @if (Model.TableDatasource != null){
                    //Write some thing to html page example: tables or span
```

}

At the first, **Model.TableDatasource** is null, user choose information and Controller Review **View(Model)** like this:

```
var model = new PrintDeliveryTicketModel()
            {
                PlantList = CommonHelper.GetPlantList(),
            };

            if (request == null)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                var currentPlant = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlantList>(request);

                var FullModel = new PrintDeliveryTicketModel()
                {
                    PlantList = CommonHelper.GetPlantList(),
                    CurrentPlant = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlantList>(request),
                    DriverList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Drivers>>(CommonHelper.GetDriver(currentPlant.CodePlant, currentPlant.PlantNo.Value).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result),
                    CustomerList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(CommonHelper.GetCustomer().Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result),
                    RecipeList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Recipe>>(CommonHelper.GetRecipe(currentPlant.CodePlant, currentPlant.PlantNo.Value).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result),
                    SitesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Site>>(CommonHelper.GetSite().Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result),
                   // TruckList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Truck>>(CommonHelper.GetTruck().Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)
                };

                return View(FullModel);

            }
```

At the Debug time, I notice that break-point stop at return **View(FullMode)** and Break-point at ViewFile(cshtml) has value. but nothing printed at view.

Hope some help.

Comment: IS this all controller code?

Comment: Yes. That all. I had send post to this controlller and as you can see. I return View with model